# Problem connecting with Listener server in High Availability

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

Recently I set up AG and server X is Primary and Server Y is secondary and Z is listener server. Ag is running fine. If I do RDP to Primary Server I can connect to Listener but Can't connect through Secondary server and from my local SSMS,I can't connect to listener at all.
We have Azure environment and I set up load balancer, Front end ip and health probe.

I checked all configurations are correct or not. There are no firewall issues.
compared with other listeners also.
can someone please help me, what I am missing..

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution.DNS was not able to communicate with Listener server.So need to run this powershell script and It worked.I am attaching link for reference.

```
$ClusterNetworkName = "<MyClusterNetworkName>" # the cluster network name (Use Get-ClusterNetwork on Windows Server 2012 of higher to find the name)
$IPResourceName = "<IPResourceName>" # the IP Address resource name
$ListenerILBIP = "<n.n.n.n>" # the IP Address of the Internal Load Balancer (ILB). This is the static IP address for the load balancer you configured in the Azure portal.
[int]$ListenerProbePort = <nnnnn>

Import-Module FailoverClusters

Get-ClusterResource $IPResourceName | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"Address"="$ListenerILBIP";"ProbePort"=$ListenerProbePort;"SubnetMask"="255.255.255.255";"Network"="$ClusterNetworkName";"EnableDhcp"=0}
```

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-alwayson-int-listener#create-an-ip-address-for-an-additional-availability-group)